# PreLoader is Not working when Event Fired

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, preloader

Am Working in jQueryMobile(jQM 1.2.1) and PhoneGap(cordova-2.7.0).
Here Now am facing a Problem with Preloader.
Here When we click Submit Button of Page1 then there is some API is send to Server. 
On the event of Pagebeforeload of Page2 We collect the result and pass to an array for fetch in HTML.Then Page 2 Shows we need to Hide the Preloader.
But the Problem is When we click Button Loading is not working.

First We check with jQM default Preloader. But when its Fails. So  I created a Preloader Manually and Call that at the time of Button Click.

```
function showLoading()
{
    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div> < img src = 'images/loading.gif' id = 'loader_image' / > ");
}
```

Here I Shows My code of Button Click Event.

```
$("#submit_booking_step_one").live('click', function(event) {

    // $.mobile.loading('show');
    showLoading();
    var Valresult = searchValidation()
    if (Valresult == true)
    {
        var json = 1;
        var age_driver = $('#age').val();
        var car_group = $('#car_group_list').val();
        var cmpapi = 'http://www.sampleurl.com/json/get.php?json=' + json + '&age_driver=' + age_driver'';
                ajaxForCmpList(cmpapi);
        //showLoading();
        $.mobile.changePage("#mobile_page_list_bookacar", {reverse: false, changeHash: true});
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Is there Any Solution for that ????

Comment: replace this `$("#submit_booking_step_one").live('click', function(event) {` with this `$(document).on('click', "#submit_booking_step_one" , function(event) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this script...

```
$(".ui-loader").show();
```

Instead of showLoading() function.

DEMO here... http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/CVv2q/1/

And also change to this event...

```
$("#submit_booking_step_one").on('vclick', function(e){
    // your scripts
});
```

## JQUERY

```
$('#submit_bkg').on('vclick', function(e){
    $(".ui-loader").show(); // onsubmit, show loading
    
    e.preventDefault();
    location.hash = "submitted_booking";  // another page  
      
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_data_source.php?qtype=new_booking',
        data: serialized,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            
            // your scripts for after successful submit
            
            $(".ui-loader").hide();  // hide loading back
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I checked with your Code... But Its Not working at the time of Button Click :( its only wrks at the time of next page load.. this same err is happening when i use showLoading() !!!

Comment: I didn't even load any page, just show loading btn1 onclick event and hide loading back on btn2 click event.

Comment: Yeah.. But I need; it will be works when we click Submit Button and hide on next page Load!!! But Now its shows only after the next pageShows (Here I comment the Hide method.. otherwise Preloader wil not shows.)

Comment: check my update answer, i added my form submit script, and how to show and hide loading

Comment: I Modified my code as your way.. but still Preloader blocked at the time of button click. :( Is this problem of my jQueryMobile version???(jQM 1.2.1)...

Comment: I think so, try to test it with jqm-1.3.1 ?
this one works well in my projects.